# Cannot use breakpoint's to debug VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a project that is build with VB.NET

VS2012 web edition .net Framwork 4.5

The previous developer had build this project without using any debugging features, yet i wish to do so,

I have managed to use the debug option, yet the breakpoints are giving me the

```
"No symbols have been loaded for this document"
```

The code is written as a "web site" - no solution file, all the aspx files are related to the VB using "codefile=" and not "codebehind" therefore there is no DLL to debug,

What can i do ?

Comment: Are you building this in Debug or Release configuration?  Does the web.config contain debug=true?

Comment: Debug, and the web.config contains it

Comment: You've recently built the code?

Comment: "The previous developer had build this project without using any debugging features." I want to meet this developer who's so good he doesn't need to debug his code.